# Flutter Behaving Strange(fBS)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Am new to flutter. I tried positioning containers in the middle of the body using `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` and `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` didn't work but was able to do `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` so I include `width: double.infinity` and all codes `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` and `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` worked just fine so I stopped `width: double.infinity` by //commenting(`//width: double.infinity`). I reloaded the app and surprisingly everything is still working I moved the Column Children around with `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` and `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` and everything is running fine without `width: double.infinity` but in the beginning it didn't work. Does it mean flutter needed `width: double.infinity` to be triggered to work correctly? Or flutter is still accessing the (`//width: double.infinity`)remotely?

Comment: In debug mode, sometime it loads caches, try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

To center UI  `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,` is not just enough because, column width will depend on its children max width.
You can do

```dart
home: Scaffold(
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) => SizedBox(
      width: constraints.maxWidth,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Another thing can be done just by wrapping the Column with `Center` widget, and it will shift to center.

```dart
home: Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

More about flutter [ui](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)